To create something from the destruction of something else
I’m getting the feeling there’s a very obvious solution here but I thought there’s no harm in asking some internet strangers for help.
Need a word to describe a god character for their title, e.g. ‘god of []’, ‘the []-(ative) god’.
Pretty much looking for a harsher word than ‘transform’. It’s a bit too neutral and I want some evil connotations.‘Manipulate’ sounds evil-er but the meaning is lost. I don’t like ‘mutate’.
Sorry if the structure of this question isn’t up to standards, I’m a first-time poster.

Providing an example sentence would be an excellent idea.

What is wrong with "god of destruction", the destructive god?  Why does the adjective have to end in -ative?

A god with evil connotations? Even Shiva, who creates, protects, destroys and transforms the universe isn't evil.

The usual expression is longer than a single word: 'rise [phoenix-like] from the ashes of'.

built on the ashes of x

@TimR "destruction" has no connotation that the god creates something new from the residue.

@TimR the adjective does not have the end in -ative, was just trying to convey the word being an adjective in that context (should have put -tive for that really). Also, yes, destruction has no connotations of creation from its aftermath.

@Weather Vane I’m not referring to a real god here, I’m looking to describe a fictional god character, which isn’t linked to any pre-existing religion.

@Reece I don't see the difference: god ~ good, devil ~ evil.

Forge or Reforge
Cambridge  says

to make or produce something, especially with some difficulty: forge a bond
The accident forged a close bond between the two families.
She forged a new career for herself as a singer.

Forging is a high temperature process and is therefore a harsher environment.
There's no really evil connotations, but one does "forge a sword" or other weapons of war.

The title of your question does not seem to bear much relation to the body of the question. Addressing the content:
OED

Demiurge:
A name for the Maker or Creator of the world, in the Platonic Philosophy; in certain later systems, as the Gnostic, conceived as a
being subordinate to the Supreme Being, and sometimes as the author of
evil.
1882 The Manichees subsequently argued, that there were two Gods—one
the supreme and illimitable Deity..the other a limited and imperfect
Demiurge. F. W. Farrar, Early Days of Christianity vol. II. 356

Thus you could say "They worshipped Tharg, the demiurge."

Sorry, I suppose my question was a bit vague. I am truly looking for a word meaning ‘to create something by destroying something else’, not a word to describe an evil god specifically. That said, I do like this term, and will probably end up using it anyways, so thanks for the answer!

"Metamorphosis" is a synonym for transformation.  It's what insects do, and many people find bugs creepy, so it has some sinister connotations.
Indeed, the details of the process sound sinister enough, even for something as G-rated as caterpillars and butterflies.  According to Scientific American:

First, the caterpillar digests itself, releasing enzymes to dissolve
all of its tissues. If you were to cut open a cocoon or chrysalis at
just the right time, caterpillar soup would ooze out.


"Metamorphosis" is entirely neutral. It is the context that creates an aspect of the word. You may have been confused by Kafka's novel.

@Greybeard I would hardly be the first to be confused by one of Kafka's stories.
However, "metamorphosis" is indeed what the transformation of an insect from larval to adult stage is called by scientists.  So, while there are indeed other usages, the association certainly exists.

Metamorphosis is a relatively common word in English and it is not worth explaining it. It is a natural process, and as such, neutral. Additionally, the agent and the patient tend to be the same NP. Finally, there is no destruction - merely a rearrangement.
